# Specify a local path for a private iOS podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am creating a Cocoapod that will be in a private repo, but I do not have a proper git server available to use. Instead, I have it on a network storage device and access it via a folder similar to this:

```
~/myDrive/git-repos/myrepo.git
```

I have setup a private spec repo that appears to work properly (it passed the validation offered on the [Cococpods site](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)).

However, trying to set a source value in the Podspec file has been quite a struggle thus far. I have reviewed the section on it ([available here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source)), and while all of their examples include git & hg repos, I did see an option to use a `:path` value. However, they do not include an example and I have been unable to find anything that works.

My most recent attempt looks like this (I have tried several variations as well):

```
s.source = { :path => '~/myDrive/git-repos/myrepo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

When I try to lint the pod, I get this error:

> - WARN  | [iOS] keys: Incompatible 'tag' key(s) with 'path' primary key for 'source' attribute.

I also tried to specify the local path (with the fully qualified name as well), and got the same result.

I did also try to use git instead, but get a different error for that:

```
s.source = { :git => '~/myDrive/git-repos/myrepo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

> fatal: repository '~/myDrive/git-repos/myrepo.git' does not exist